# custom Listview is not displaying as it should

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I've created the format for my list items and my custom listadapter.  The problem is that my listview is not displaying as i designed it to.

Here is my XML for each list item.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Some more information" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Some Information" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code, as you can see i am trying to use a view holder because i heard it was the most efficient way:

```
public class FirstLoginActivity extends ListActivity {
        Context mContext;
        List mList;
        String[] testcontacts;

        MessageView aa = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            testcontacts = getResources()
                    .getStringArray(R.array.testcontacts_array);

            aa = new MessageView();
            // setContentView(R.layout.firstList);
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setAdapter(aa);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        class MessageView extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            MessageView() {
                super(FirstLoginActivity.this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item,
                        testcontacts);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
                Log.d("Ebz", "inside getView method");
                ViewHolder holder;
                View v = convertview;
                if (v == null) {
                    Log.d("Ebz", "if v == null");
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.firstLine = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
                    holder.secondLine = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
                    holder.icon1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon1);
                    holder.icon2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
                    v.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                }
                holder.firstLine.setText(testcontacts[position]);
                holder.secondLine.setText(testcontacts[position]);
                holder.icon1.setImageBitmap(null);
                holder.icon2.setImageBitmap(null);
                // call the images directly?
                return v;
            }

            class ViewHolder {
                TextView firstLine;
                TextView secondLine;
                ImageView icon1;
                ImageView icon2;

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the xml that i want to display when the activity is called, with the list items in the format that i created previously.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/titlebar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Messages"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="14.5dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When i said another way in my bounty message, i meant another more effecient way, Thank You

Comment: Does it display the items if you do not use the ViewHolder. ?   And use `getitem` instead of `testcontacts[position]` inside adapter's `getView` callback.

Comment: So how should it be displayed and how is it actually displayed? Screenshots might be helpful.

Comment: Yes please put the Screen shot what you display. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. No one have given you a right Answer. Well i have solve your issue.
You are not getting that layout as because in getView method you are passing the String[] but you are extending the ArrayAdapter.

You should have to pass the ArrayList for the ArrayAdapter.

See below SOLVED code:

```
package com.exmple.helperStackOverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstLoginActivity extends ListActivity {         
    private ArrayList<String> m_orders = null;
    private MessageView aa;
    private String[] testcontacts = new String[] {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"};
    protected static LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstlist);

        m_orders = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.aa = new MessageView(this, R.layout.list_items, m_orders);
        setListAdapter(this.aa);

        getOrders();
    }

    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                aa.add(m_orders.get(i));
            }
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    private void getOrders(){
          try{
              m_orders = new ArrayList<String>();
              for (int i = 0; i < testcontacts.length; i++){
                m_orders.add(testcontacts[i]);
              }
              Thread.sleep(100);
              Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
            } catch (Exception e) { 
              Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
            }
            runOnUiThread(returnRes);
        }
    private class MessageView extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private ArrayList<String> items;

        public MessageView(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> items) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                this.items = items;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
                }
                String o = items.get(position);
                if (o != null) {
                        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
                        //ImageView im = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                        if (tt != null) {
                              tt.setText(testcontacts[position]);  
                        }
//                      
                }
                return v;
        }
    }
 }
```

If still you dont get then let me know as i have completly solve your issue.

**Update**

If you want to Implement the ViewHolder for this ListView then see below:

First create the class of ViewHolder:

```
public static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView tt;
    public TextView bt;
    public ImageView leftImage;
    public ImageView rightImage;
}
```

Now just replace your getView Method with below method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (v == null) {
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);

                holder.tt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
                holder.bt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
                holder.leftImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon1); // For ImageView
                holder.rightImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon2); // For ImageView

                v.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
                holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
            String o = items.get(position);
            holder.tt.setText(testcontacts[position]);
            holder.bt.setText("First Line");

            if (o != null) {                        
            }

      return v;
    }
```

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Hey man, your code really did help thank A lot, but it still isnt displaying my xml like i designed it too.  With the 2 images views and the two text fields.

Comment: Ok then let me check your xml code. . .  i will reply you soon. . .

Comment: @TheObliviator: please Just copy paste my code and try it for your data. As because it works perfect for me. . .

Comment: @TheObliviator: Have try it or not ?? Give responce.

Comment: I wanted it to display the 2 imageviews and 2 text fields but ill try it right now copy and paste

Comment: Please put the screenshot of what you get after using this java code. . .  As i have just copy paste your xml and use my java code and it works proper. . .

Comment: You are right man.  The problem was on my behalf.. Thanks alot bro.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7830/discussion-between-the-obliviator-and-idroid-explorer)

Comment: Ok Thanks Man. ..  And from next time try to use the answer code first and then leave comment. Enjoy. :)

Comment: I've already accepted your method, but now that i found that error, how would i be able to implement the Viewholder?

Comment: Why you want to implement the View Holder ? You can implement it as you have done before. Or wait. . .  Let me update the Answer. . .

Comment: I want to implement viewholder because it is the most efficient way to scroll through text views, and thanks again for the help

Comment: See updated answer. I have implemented the ViewHolder for you.

Comment: reply me it it not works or is there any other issue. Enjoy coading. . .

Comment: Thanks for all your help man! you have helped me relieve a lot of stress haha

Comment: Welcome Budy. Enjoy Coading.  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <ListView        
   android:id="@android:id/list"         
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
   android:layout_height="0dip"       
   android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar" 
   android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
   android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"        
   android:divider="#FFFFFF"         
   android:dividerHeight="14.5dp" >    
 </ListView>
```

In this piece of code you have given `android:layout_height="0dip"` which is causing your problem.  Either make it `wrap_content`, `fill_parent` or give it some fixed value such as `200dip`.

Note that the last option will set the list height to `200dip` so if you want exact size that will make it fit between `top_control_bar` and `bottom_control_bar`

Try to generate your ui from the java file as:

```
 ListView list = new ListView(this);
 list.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,getScreenHeight()-(top_control_bar_height + bottom_control_bar_height));
 this.addView(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

First this will not work any way in image view:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Remove `android:layout_height="0dip"` from list view and change it to `fill_parent`. Both can not work together. Use `android:layout_alignparent="center_vertical"`. For a better answer, you should paste images of the design you want.